# "Maven builds are failing with "javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated" for Java 7 and Java 6

Tags: maven

Effective January 15, 2020, The Central Repository no longer supports insecure communication over plain HTTP and requires that all requests to the repository are encrypted over HTTPS

We changed our maven central repo from HTTP to HTTPS where builds are working fine for Java version 8 but failing for Java 7 and 6 with the error as

```
 Error: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:2.1.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin:jar:2.1.2: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins:pom:18 from/to central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/): peer not authenticated -> [Help 1]
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please take some time to read [How to ask good questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Update your question with complete error log (error in the title doesn't appear in the error log in description.)

Comment: You need to configure to use TLSv1.2 at least for Java 7 ..I'm not sure if it's possible to use that in Java 6 as well...

Answer (score 0):

Set up a local repository instructed to mirror Maven Central and use that mirror for your builds.

Nexus is configured to do so out of the box, and can easily be run as a docker instance.